# Capacitors and electrical energy

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

We know that the potential energy stored ina capacitor connected to battery of emf V is: (1/2)QV . But the work done by battery in the process is QV where does the half goes ?

Comment: Half is lost as heat

Comment: Answered before the duplicate was found but agree it's a duplicate